# Split an array into small arrays based on text in values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have big array, which looks like this example:

```
let array = ['aa-we', 'aa-we__qq', 'aa-we__qw', 'gsPlsOdd', 'bc-po-lp', 'bc-po-lp--ps', 'de', 'de__io', 'de__sl', 'de--xz', 'ccsDdd'];
```

i want split this array into small arrays by values:

```
let array = [
  ['aa-we', 'aa-we__qq', 'aa-we__qw'],
  ['bc-po-lp', 'bc-po-lp--ps'],
  ['de', 'de__io', 'de__sl', 'de--xz']  
]

// and camelcase strings should be removed
```

Values in array have syntax like BEM selectors, so if the prefix of different strings is the same, they should be wrapped in a single array.

How can i do this, if possible, without additional libraries?

Thanks for the help or tips!

Comment: could it be an object, too?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @yunzen no, array only.

Comment: Why isn't `gsPlsOdd` in the output but `de` is?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I guess because `gsPlsOdd` is camelcase. OP has written in a code comment "and camelcase strings should be removed"

Comment: @MarkMeyer because i don't need strings written in camelCase.

Comment: Are the items considered to be all lowercase()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
console.clear()
let data = [
  "aa-we",
  "aa-we__qq",
  "aa-we__qw",
  "gsPlsOdd",
  "bc-po-lp",
  "bc-po-lp--ps",
  "de",
  "de__io",
  "de__sl",
  "de--xz",
  "ccsDdd",
];


resultO = data.reduce((acc, val, idx) => {
  if (val.match(/[A-Z]/)) {return acc;}
  const sel = val.replace(/^(.*)(__|--).*$/g, "$1");
  acc[sel] = acc[sel] || [];
  acc[sel].push(val)
  return acc;
}, {})
resultA = Object.values(resultO)

console.log(resultA)
```

Comment: I also like James Coyle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647230/476951). It has a more generalized approach

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like this and then filter out what you don't want.

```js
let array = ['aa-we', 'aa-we__qq', 'aa-we__qw', 'gsPlsOdd', 'bc-po-lp', 'bc-po-lp--ps', 'de', 'de__io', 'de__sl', 'de--xz', 'ccsDdd'];

array = array.filter((a) => !a.match(/[A-Z]/))

let result = groupBy(array, (str)=> str.split(/[-_]/)[0])

console.log(Object.values(result))

function groupBy(arr, condition) {
  return arr.reduce((result, current) => {
    const key = condition(current);
    (result[key] || (result[key] = [])).push(current)
    return result
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: See comments under question. No camel case like `gsPlsOdd`.

Comment: Hence the "and then filter out what you don't want".

Comment: Didn’t see that.  Wouldn’t it be a better idea to filter as you go through the list so you don’t have look at everything twice.

Comment: Updated to do that.

Comment: You could even modify the function passed to `groupBy` to group anything invalid into a single key and then `delete` that key or could modify the groupBy function to be more specialized for the task. I just grabbed it from my helper methods.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm can be as follows:

1. Create `Map<Prefix,ValuesArray>`
2. For each element in array:

   - Get it's prefix, e.g. "ab", skip element if invalid (e.g. no prefix exist or camel case)
   - Add to corresponding hashed bucket
3. Join values from `Map` into one array

JS has all the primitives to implement this, just take a look at Map/Object for hashing and Array (`map`/`filter`/`reduce`) for processing.